# How to decorate a Web Component class

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I'm creating a @Component decorator that intercedes the constructor of a class to carry out some work after construction. As can be seen in the following code, the work is implemented in an `init` method.

```
export function Component (Cls) {
  function Class (...args) {
    let self = new Cls (...args); // (1)
    init (self, ...args);
    return self;
  }
  Class.prototype = Cls.prototype;
  return Class;
}
```

When I test this code on a regular class all works fine. This is a working example:

```
class Base { ... }

@Component
class Core extends Base {
  constructor () {
    super (); // init is invoked
  }
  fx () { console.log ('Core.fx') }
  fy () { console.log ('Core.fy') }
}
```

Nevertheless, when I try to decorate a web component a `TypeError: Illegal constructor` message is obtained.

```
@Component
class Core extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super ();
  }
  fx () { console.log ('Core.fx') }
  fy () { console.log ('Core.fy') }
}
customElements.define ('x-core', Core);

let coreX = document.createElement ('x-core');
document.body.appendChild (coreX);
```

I realise the problem is that `HTMLElement`'s do not support direct construction through new operator - see (1) on first listing - but I need a procedure to decorate constructor of any class even though they are custom elements.

Some Idea?

Working Settings: Chrome 68 · Babel 7.0.0-beta.51 with babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

Comment: how you use `Core` if you cannot `new` it at all? the `Component` here is not really matter IMHO.

Comment: Thanks a lot @appleapple I have complete the latter snippet. In my first redaction I did not include the 3 last lines so there was the same problem exist but the error was not fired.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a class to avoid direct `new`.

```js
function Component(cls) {
  class c extends cls {
    constructor() {
      super()
      console.log(this)//init
    }
  }
  return c
}
```

Comment: Good solution @appleapple. The problem is that this approach is quite invasive. You are augmenting the inheritance chain and so a lot of my tests are broken. Through decoration the architecture find a child class where it is expected the parent (original level) class

Comment: @JavierVélez I don't get what you say. decorated class is replacing origin class. you should not notice any difference.

Comment: Just as an example, in other point of my architecture I need to recover class members by `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. Right now this method works fine on the architecture. If you generate a new child class by `@Component` decorator, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` returns [] so the whole architecture fails. I cannot asume this critical change overall the architecture because not all target classes are to be decorated by `@Component`